# Set the same height to a TextView and an EditText in a row of a TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview, android-tablelayout

I need a TableLayout with TextViews and EditTexts and it should be like a crossword puzzle.

I've tested this with `LinearLayout, width=0dp and weight=1,` but it didn't worked like I wanted. Then I've tried it with a TableLayout and I think I'm near to the solution. I've tested with heights and widths in the XML or in the Java but it didn't work. My Problem now is that all TextViews are thinner than the EditText and I don't know why and how I can make them look the same.

XML-files:

```
<!-- activity_sraetsel_main.xml -->
<TableLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical" >        
</TableLayout>

<!-- activity_sraetsel_row.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
</TableRow>

<!-- activity_sraetsel_edittext.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLength="1">
</EditText>

<!-- activity_sraetsel_textview.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="6.5sp"
        android:singleLine = "false" >
</TextView>

<!-- cell_border.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#515151"/>
<padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp"
android:right="10dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

and the java part, where I put all together:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.table);
for (int y = 0; y < hoehe; y++) {
    // Inflate your row "template" and fill out the fields.
    TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_sraetsel_row, null);
    for (int x = 0; x < breite; x++) {
        if (raetsel[y][x].startsWith(",", 1)) {
            EditText eText = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_sraetsel_edittext, null);
            if (!(raetsel[y][x].startsWith("a"))) {
                eText.setText(raetsel[y][x].substring(0, 1));
            } //if
            eText.setWidth(60);
            eText.setHeight(60);
            row.addView(eText);
            Log.d(TAG, "SRaetselMain, AntwortFeld erstellt");
        } else {
            TextView vText = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_sraetsel_textview, null);
            vText.setText(raetsel[y][x].substring(0, raetsel[y][x].indexOf("|")));
            vText.setWidth(60);
            vText.setHeight(60);
            row.addView(vText);
            Log.d(TAG, "SRaetselMain, FrageFeld erstellt");
        } //if
    } //for
    table.addView(row);
} //for

table.requestLayout();
```

And finally how it looks like:
[image]

**EDIT1:**
With `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for TextView in XML and without the setHeight() for TextView in Activity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/btzj4.png

**EDIT2:**
With `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"`it looks the same like EDIT1

Now I've tested it without TextViews and only with EditText, and I found that the problem is the textSize. If I make the TextView without the option `android:textSize="6.5sp"` it works. But then the text is to big and unfortunately I need this text that small.

**EDIT3:**
I've tried this with LinearLayout and with two TextViews.
I really don't know how I can change that this two Views are at the same height.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIENf.png

Thank you for your help in this matter.

Comment: Screenshot image link is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to my own Question:

The Problem is solved with this: `android:baselineAligned="false"`
Put this line into this XML and it works!

```
 <!-- activity_sraetsel_row.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
</TableRow>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for `TextView` in XML and remove the `setHeight()` for `TextView` in `Activity`. Since, you are setting size of `EditText` manually, so, there is no need for change in it. By doing this `TextView` will take all the space for `height`.

**EDIT**

```
<!-- activity_sraetsel_edittext.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLength="1">
</EditText>

<!-- activity_sraetsel_textview.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="6.5sp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine = "false" >
</TextView>
```

Try setting `layout_height` to `0dp` and `layout_weight` to `1`.

If you want same height of both `View`s then `layout_weight` could help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Unfortunately the TextView isn't square.
I'll put a link to the question with the new screenshot

Comment: I've tried this, but I don't understand what's wrong. I've copy/paste your XML with the option `android:layout_width="60dp"` but the cells are as width as the text in it. Now I've tested it without TextViews and only EditText, and I found that the problem is the textSize. If I make the TextView without the option `android:textSize="6.5sp"` it works. But unfortunately I need this text that small.

Comment: If you need text size to be small then you can try `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`

Comment: With that command the text appears with 14sp and this is to big for the TextView. 
I'll test now with an other Layout, perhaps that will work.
If you've another idea how I can fit the TextView in the TableRow let me know it. Thank you for your help!